# How do I fix this bug in Unity C# with getting a variable through reflection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

I have this code to find my variable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MoneyScript MS;

    [SerializeField] GameObject ChosenObject;
    string VarName = "speed";
    public float Price;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        var Instance = ChosenObject.GetComponent<UpgradeValues>();
        var Value = typeof(UpgradeValues).GetField(VarName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Instance);
        Value = 100;
    }
}
```

And the variable lies in this script. It is minimal because I just want to know how to use this for my actual project.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpgradeValues : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3;
}
```

I was tried this code and it didn't supply any bugs! But, the variable was simply not converting.

Comment: What do you mean by "not converting"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why does yours not work?

Your `Value` from

```
var Value = typeof(UpgradeValues).GetField(VarName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Instance);
```

is a simple `float` (boxed in `object`). This is a [**Value type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) - meaning it is **no reference** but always a **copy** of the value in memory - and is in no way at all *linked* to the underlying field where you originally **copied** this value from!

So when you do

```
Value = 100;
```

all you do is overwriting your local value of your `Value` variable. This would actually even be the case if your field *was* a reference type anyway since as said you are just re-assigning your variable, not modifying any property of the thing you stored in it.

---

#### (Preferred) Solution

Well you would actually first of all **not use Reflection at all** in your use case!

You already **have** the according instance reference

```
var Instance = ChosenObject.GetComponent<UpgradeValues>();
```

your field is `public` so visible to all anyway. So you would rather simply go through

```
Instance.speed = 100f;
```

Done!

You could even go further and directly use the correct type for your exposed field and do (you will have to re-assign the field(s))

```
[SerializeField] private UpgradeValues ChosenObject;
```

and then simply do

```
ChosenObject.speed = 100f;
```

---

#### Reflection (don't!)

**IF** for whatever weird reason you still want to use reflection

You would rather store the [`FieldInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo) reference

```
var valueField = typeof(UpgradeValues).GetField(VarName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

and then use

```
valueField.SetValue(Instance, 100f);
```

but again: **I really don't see any reason why you would go for this in your case**

Comment: Thanks derHugo! The reason I wanted reflection was because I had a major problem with my upgrading system. I listed out every single reference for all my shops and then just inputted a serialized integer to differentiate scripts. Now I can easily get all of my values by using a serialized string.